# Fine tuning jq filters to reduce repetition in filter string

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a complex JSON object produced from an API call (full JSON found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pchittum/eb28adc39cd7c95b51489805a409204e)). It's describing attributes of an entity (fields, parameters, child relationships, etc.). Using `jq`, I'm trying to extract just one child field array and convert it to CSV where field keys are a single header row and values of each array item form the subsequent rows. (NOTE: fields are uniform across all items in the array.)

So far I'm successful, but I feel as if my `jq` filter string could be better as there is a repetition of unpacking this array in two separate filters.

Here is a redacted version of the JSON for reference:

```
    {
        ...
        "result": {
            ... 
            "fields": [
                {
                    "aggregatable": true,
                    "aiPredictionField": false,
                    "autoNumber": false,
                    "byteLength": 18,
                    "name": "Id",
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "aggregatable": true,
                    "aiPredictionField": false,
                    "autoNumber": false,
                    "byteLength": 18,
                    "name": "OwnerId",
                    ... 
                },
                {
                    "aggregatable": false,
                    "aiPredictionField": false,
                    "autoNumber": false,
                    "byteLength": 0,
                    "name": "IsDeleted",
                    ...
                },
                ...
            ],
            ...
        }
    }
```

So far, here is the working command:

```
jq -r '.result.fields | (.[0] | keys) , .[] | [.[] | tostring] | @csv'

repeated array unpacking---^-------------^
```

I could be happy with this, but I would prefer to unpack the `result.fields` array in the first filter so that it starts out like this:

```
jq -r '.result.fields[] | ...
```

Only then there is no longer an array, just a set of objects. I tried several things but none of them gave me what I wanted. Here two things I tried before I realized that unpacking `.result.fields[]` destroyed anything array-like for me to work with (yep...slow learner here, and can be a bit thick):

```
jq -r '.result.fields[] | ( keys | .[0] ) , [.[] | tostring] | @csv'
jq -r '.result.fields[] |  keys[0]  , [.[] | tostring] | @csv'
```

So the real question is: can I unpack `result.fields` once and then work with what that gives me? And if not, is there a more efficient way to arrive at the CSV structure I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code is buggy, because `keys` sorts the keys.  What's needed here is `keys_unsorted`.
2. If you want to accomplish everything in a single invocation of jq, you cannot start the pipeline with `result.fields[]`.
3. The following does avoid one very small inefficiency of your approach:

`.result.fields
    | (.[0] | keys_unsorted), 
      (.[] | [.[] | tostring])
    | @csv`

Comment: 1. Nice one. I had read about `keys_unsorted` at one point. But then forgot as I got into this. As luck would have it, this API produces the fields in alpha order anyway, but you're absolutely right that a proper general-purpose approach to this problem should use `keys_unsorted`. Thanks!

Comment: 3. All I see is that you've added parens around `.[] | [.[] | tostring]`. Is this just a matter of making it stylistically more readable? Or does this do something else?

Comment: You can use `debug` to see the difference.  Or just consider the difference between `1,2|debug` and `1,(2|debug)`.